# How to connect to a MySQL container from a different docker container over a docker network

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to connect to a MySQL container from another docker container.

I created a network:

```
docker network create netw
```

I created the MySQL container:

```
docker run --name oates -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=localdb -p 3307:3306 --net=netw -d mysql:latest
```

I created a container from the official Drupal image:

```
docker run --name morse -p 8080:80 --net=netw -d drupal:latest
```

I then enter the Drupal container:

```
docker exec -it morse /bin/bash
```

And I attempt a remote connection a few different ways:

```
mysql -h oates -u root -p
mysql -h oates --port 3307 -u root -p
mysql -h 172.18.0.2 --port 3307 -u root -p
```

The output is always: "bash: mysql: command not found".

In case I am not using the correct host, here is the IP output if I inspect the mysql container:

```
$ docker inspect oates | grep IP
            "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
            "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
            "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
            "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
            "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "IPAddress": "",
            "IPPrefixLen": 0,
            "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "IPAMConfig": null,
                    "IPAddress": "172.18.0.2",
                    "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
```

It looks to me like there is an IP for the network but not the MySQL container, but I'm not sure I understand the output.

Notes:

- I am avoiding the use of **--link** since that is apparently no longer
  the preferred approach, and it doesn't seem practical to connect to a
  newly created container that way.
- I am new to docker, and it's not yet clear to me that **docker compose** can be used in an ad hoc way to connect an existing container to another newly created container.  But I would be interested to know if it can.

Comment: "*The output is always: "bash: mysql: command not found".*" - Looks like there's no mysql client cli installed in the dupral image.

Comment: @Turing85  Thanks.  That was most of the problem. I needed a db client, like you said. Though in this case I needed mariadb-client as explained in my answer below.

Comment: This is probably somewhat easier to set up in Compose, since by default it creates a network and attaches all containers to it; see [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) for more details.

Comment: @DavidMaze  Docker attaches all containers to the bridge network by default.  No need for Compose.  It was extremely easy once I grasped that I needed a database client in the container that uses the database service.  Thanks.

Comment: For historical reasons, if you `docker run` with no `--network` options, you wind up attached to a "default bridge network" that's a remnant of the first-generation Docker setup.  You need some `--network` option to attach to a "user-defined bridge network"; see [Use bridge networks](https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/) in the Docker documentation.  That `docker network create` and `docker run --net` option setup is the thing Compose handles automatically for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to install mariadb client:

```
apt update
apt install mariadb-client
```

Apparently the mariadb client is compatible with mysql-client and is the right client for my Drupal container.

I also was wrong to specify port 3307.  I suppose from the Drupal container's perspective, the port is 3306, so no port needs to be specified, and this simple connection string works...

```
mysql -h oates -u root -p
```